# Is it any opportunity to set label to query in EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework to generate sql queries. And DB admins send me queries which are too slow or not optimized. But in app are hundreds requests to DB and too hard to find right one.
Is it any possibilities to set label in query? I need it to find query faster than I do it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depends a little on your EF version ...

in EF6 for example you could take the command interception approach to modify all SQL statements EF generates ...

see https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/database-command-interception.aspx